# open networked files and folders in web browser across differing platforms

Tags: javascript, html, windows, macos, pdf

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give me on this matter.

I am currently trying to figure out a good approach to achieve the following tasks.

I need to provide an easy way for users on our LAN to view PDFs and open folders from within a web browser.  The solution needs to be cross platform (currently Mac & PC) with the future need to display the PDFs on company tablets (Android, iPAD etc).

There are thousands of numbered folders on our file server and ideally the user would enter a folder number into a web page, and click one of two buttons, either 'View PDF' or 'Open Parent Folder'.

I have found solutions to viewing the PDFs (see below) and some basic testing it seems promising.  Converting to an image first is mostly for me due to the need for speed with the future tablet requirements.

[Initial Zoom Parameter for PDF Object in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11938141/initial-zoom-parameter-for-pdf-object-in-html5)

I can see how the solution below can solve the problem on Windows for me but I'm struggling to find a solution for the Mac.

[Open Explorer window from Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431112/open-explorer-window-from-website)

Ideally I'd like to achieve this using a combination of PHP (apache web server), HTML and Javascript (if needs be) as these are the languages I'm experience of.

Any ideas/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about setting up FTP Server? you can search, setup permissions and you can access from anywhere. Like https://filezilla-project.org/

Comment: Thanks SQLSurfer. I'm not sure ftp will work for what I need hear as the ability to open folders from the browser needs to breakout to Windows Explorer &OR Finder on OSX. Am figuring I need to pass found folder to a script of some form which when exec'd will open the given folder in the OS.

Comment: FYI, I have found a solution to the problem of accessing folders on the server via the Mac.  **http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/linktrigger/** has given me a solution and with some changes it is working for me... it's not perfect as in the user has to download the helper app first time round but after that it works a treat.  Good for my intranet app but wouldn't use it anywhere else (security).